# Modern research on the subjectivity of sense-impressions, species, and Aristotelian conceptions of the world?

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, qualia

In my research on the Philosophy of Data, I've found some remarkable similarities between some peoples' conceptions of data and the Aristotelian idea of Species, the particles of experience/sense-impression carried by media. For example, according to Aristotle, light carries visual species which are received by the eyes and interpreted. A lack of light means the species generated by an object cannot be *transmitted* rather than not being generated.

Are there any modern philosophers looking at our subjective impressions of the world and connecting these thoughts to Aristotle?

Answer (score 1):

This may be well be one way to state what phenomenology does; although not an explicit return-to-the-Greeks, Husserl and other phenomenologists are definitely engaged with the first person study of the structures of qualia (and more generally of consciousness and intentionality.) There is a decidedly "inward" or subjective bent to these analyses:

> Basically, phenomenology studies the structure of various types of experience ranging from perception, thought, memory, imagination, emotion, desire, and volition to bodily awareness, embodied action, and social activity, including linguistic activity. The structure of these forms of experience typically involves what Husserl called “intentionality”, that is, the directedness of experience toward things in the world, the property of consciousness that it is a consciousness of or about something. According to classical Husserlian phenomenology, our experience is directed toward — represents or “intends” — things only through particular concepts, thoughts, ideas, images, etc. These make up the meaning or content of a given experience, and are distinct from the things they present or mean.

(From the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on Phenomenology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/).)